# How to calculate the limit for average number of rounds in a game

Tags: limits

tl;dr:

How do I calculate the solution to the following limit:

[image: picture1]

Concrete example for $x= \frac{1}{4}$

[image: picture2]

Context:

I'm working on an odds calculator for an online board game and I've run into the following problem. I need to calculate how many rounds a certain battle will last. However, there is a theoretical possibility that the battle will last forever, because both sides may always miss.

To solve this, I have to calculate the mathematical limit.

For example: both sides have 1 unit, and each unit has a 50% chance of hitting. Therefore there is a 75% chance that both or one of the units will hit, and the battle will end after 1 round. If they both miss, a second round is started.

Therefore, the average number of rounds that the battle will last can be expressed as $\frac{3}{4}$ +

[image: picture2]

See: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim+sum%28%281%2F4%29**n*%282-%281%2F4%29%29%29+as+n-%3Einfinity

or

[image: picture1]

See: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim+sum%28%28x%29**n*%282-%28x%29%29%29+as+n-%3Einfinity

where $x$ is the chance of the battle not ending.

Running my simulator tells me that the outcome of $\frac{3}{4} + \frac{7}{12}$ is correct for $x=\frac{1}{4}$, but how do I calculate this?

Comment: Assuming $|x|<1$  you have $\sum\limits_1^\infty x^n= \dfrac{x}{1-x}$ so $\sum\limits_1^\infty x^n (2-x) = \dfrac{x(2-x)}{1-x}$

Comment: Awesome, thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for!